# Stripping similar elements from the beginning of two lists

Tags: python

Do you know a more efficient, elegant and pythonic way to compare two lists and return both lists without the similar elements at the start as well as the common list head?

```py
list1 = ['A', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements']
list2 = ['A', 'list', 'with', 'some', 'text', 'elements']
list3 = ['The', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements']

# my current implementation
def strip_head(list1, list2):
    similar = []
    while list1 and list2 and list1[0] == list2[0]:
        similar.append(list1.pop(0))
        list2.pop(0)
    return similar, list1, list2

print(strip_head(list1, list2))  # >>> (['A', 'list', 'with'], ['text', 'elements'], ['some', 'text', 'elements'])
list1 = ['A', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements']  # reset list1 since it has been altered by pop
print(strip_head(list1, list3))  # >>> ([], ['A', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements'], ['The', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements'])
```

Comment: Hi @Georgy, thanks for the hint! Yeah, I would say that's what I was looking for but couldn't articulate the right search terms for. In hindsight it seems so straight forward...

Answer (score 3):

One way to improve can be to just figure out the index where the values start to diverge. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) allows you to iterate through two lists at once, while `enumerate` can keep track of indexes. Then, just slice based on the index.

```
list1 = ['A', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements']
list2 = ['A', 'list', 'with', 'some', 'text', 'elements']
list3 = ['The', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements']

def strip_head_slicing(list1, list2):
    for idx, (l, r) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
        if l != r:
            break
    else:
        idx += 1 #to account for cases where an entire list matched
    return list1[:idx], list1[idx:], list2[idx:]

print(strip_head_slicing(list1, list2))
#(['A', 'list', 'with'], ['text', 'elements'], ['some', 'text', 'elements'])
print(strip_head_slicing(list1, list3))
#([], ['A', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements'], ['The', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements'])
print(strip_head_slicing([1, 2], [1, 2, 3]))
#([1, 2], [], [3])
```

This will be slightly faster for most inputs. More importantly, this ensures the original lists are not being mutated. Functions that mutate parameters can lead to really subtle and annoying bugs down the line.

Answer (score 3):

You might also try [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to get the number of equal elements and then use slicing to get the resulting lists. Also, I would not both modify the lists *and* return the modified versions.

```
from itertools import takewhile
def strip_head(list1, list2):
    k = sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda t: t[0]==t[1], zip(list1, list2)))
    return list1[:k], list1[k:], list2[k:]
```

Or maybe use `next` to get the index of the first pair that is *not* equal, if any:

```
def strip_head(list1, list2):
    try:
        k = next(i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) if a != b)
        return list1[:k], list1[k:], list2[k:]
    except StopIteration:
        return list1[:], [], []
```

Results, for both ways:

```
>>> list1 = ['A', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements']
>>> list2 = ['A', 'list', 'with', 'some', 'text', 'elements']
>>> list3 = ['The', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements']
>>> strip_head(list1, list2)
(['A', 'list', 'with'], ['text', 'elements'], ['some', 'text', 'elements'])
>>> strip_head(list1, list3)
([], ['A', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements'], ['The', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements'])
>>> strip_head(list1, list1)
(['A', 'list', 'with', 'text', 'elements'], [], [])
```